# In 3-tiered relationship (User-Post-Comment), should user model include has_many :comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Or is enough to simply have:

user.rb

```
has_many :posts
```

post.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :comment
```

Or should comment.rb include

```
belongs_to :user
```

and user.rb include

```
has_many :comments
```

?

To help, here's my db schema:

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "posts", "users"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit:

Regarding these queries:

(1) query all other users' comments on this particular post for this particular user's comments.
And (2) query all the original user's comments on this particular post.

For (1), you will need to change the comments table to have a `comment_id`, which is the comment its responding to.

Then you can have in `comment.rb`: `belongs_to :comment`.

To get all the comments on a given post for a given comment, you'll query like this:

`Comment.where(comment: parent_comment, post: some_post) # parent_comment & post must be set somewhere`
This should return all comments that are responding to `parent_comment` for `some_post`.

For (2), you will need to add a `user_id` column to comments table, and add the following associations:

```
# comment.rb
belongs_to :user

# user.rb
has_many :comments
```

Then query the user's comments like this:
`some_user.comments.where(post: some_post) # some_user & some_post must be set beforehand`

This will return all comments made by `some_user` on `some_post`.

## Original answer:

If the `comments` table does not have a `user_id` column; then you cannot have it associated with a user with `belongs_to :user`.

If you want a way to get all comments made by a user on any post, you can use `has_many :comment, through: :posts` in the `User` model. For example:

```
# user.rb

has_many :posts
has_many :comments, through: :posts

#post.rb    
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments

#comment.rb    
belongs_to :post
```

Now you can do something like `User.find(1).comments` and you'll get all comments made by said user.

Whether you should have this or not depends on your use-case; do you need to get all comments made by a user? if yes, then you should do that way. Otherwise your original models were fine.

Comment: I'll need to see your DB schema. Is the comment connected to the user directly? What sort of queries are you trying to do?

Comment: Schema posted. So each user would have posts, on show.html of which they can post comments they themselves post. Other users would then be able to post comments to these comments, while on the same show.html. I want to (1) query all other users' comments on this particular post for this particular user's comments. And (2) query all the original user's comments on this particular post. ...may be confusing.

Comment: I see now, answer updated to reflected the changes needed to implement (1) & (2).